# Neither user 10034 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

Actually i'm having some problems with my App on devices with **Android 4.2.2**

Actually the App works well on all devices instead of a range of devices that uses radio frequency instead of Wi-Fi (Those devices are using Android 4.2.2).

Build gradle is set to `compileSdkVersion` 27 and `minSdkVersion` to 17.

What is happening is that the app just suddenly crash by sending the following logs to firebase:

```
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1425)
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1379)
android.os.IPowerManager$Stub$Proxy.acquireWakeLock (IPowerManager.java:299)
android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquireLocked (PowerManager.java:770)
android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire (PowerManager.java:755)
android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService (WakefulBroadcastReceiver.java:108)
com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver.doStartService (Origine sconosciuta:8)
com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzbm.onReceive (Origine sconosciuta:38)
com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver.onReceive (Origine sconosciuta:6)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2376)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:141)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1310)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5041)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:795)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:562)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

Actually today arrived one of those devices so i could debug it, but i just can't reply that crash while on the clients devices it happens often...

Here is my manifest permissions if they can be useful (WAKE_LOCK is in)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.camera.focus" />
```